# Install Keras and Tensorflow for R

Tags: r, tensorflow

I would like to install Keras and Tensorflow for R and I don't know why but I can't. I got a Miniconda installation though.

Even if I try to use my Miniconda path I still have the same error when I try to install Keras or Tensorflow I get the same error.

Here's my code:

```
use_condaenv("miniconda3", required = TRUE)
install.packages('keras') 
install.packages('tensorflow') 
library(keras) 
library(tensorflow) 
install_keras() 
install_tensorflow()
```

The error comes with *install_keras()* (or *install_tensorflow()*, whatever the first row is):

```
Error: installation of 'python=3.7' into environment '.../r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate' failed [error code 1]
```

But this is not my *miniconda3* path. I'm using this path for r-reticulate in order to generate R Markdown documents including both R and Python code.

Is there a simple way to install Keras and Tensorflow for R?

Thanks so much

Comment: An installation instruction can be found here: https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/guide/keras/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried that but with the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to make sure we have DevTools installed so we can import the necessary packages, then install Keras.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. I already tried this option. Devtools is installed, but I got this message when I try to install Keras using this statement: installation of package ‘[path...]/keras_2.7.0.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: This answer only addresses installing the R package keras, not the Python module Keras.